# pandas csv resampling not working

Tags: python, csv, pandas

I read a csv with

```
pandas.read_csv('/path/me/this.csv', index_col = 'Date', parse_dates = True)
```

I can slice the dates normally. The remaining columns are in proper numeric format.

But when i try to resample with lambda like

`Data.Close.resample('W', how = lambda y: y[-1])` i get an :

```
IndexError: index out of bounds.
```

Resampling by how = 'sum' works normally.

Why isnt this working? Is there another way to do it? Id like to resample the data by quarter or week and get the difference from the start of the period. End / Start -1. 
Thanks.

Comment: Can you provide an example dataframe which has the issue?

Comment: what exactly do you imagine this lambda would do in the context of resampling?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to access the last element, instead you can use `how='last'`:

```
Data.Close.resample('W', how ='last')
```

Comment: Thanks that was it. I just wanted to access the last value in the re sampled range, and i accessed also the first value the same way using how = 'first'.